# Bootstrap3 sub menu hide onclick sub items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I clicked on sub menu item my menu get closed, if I clinked on sub menu items. Please let me know how can I avoid this. 
Actually "open" class get remove on clicking sub item.

```
<ul class='wraplist' style="height: auto">
    <li class="">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span class="title">{{app.translateByLocale('menu_home')}}/span>
            <span class="arrow "></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li submenu ng-show="app.checkOffSectionConfig('app_home')">
                <a href="#" ui-sref="app.home">{{app.translateByLocale('menu_home_dashboard')}}</a>
            </li>
            <li submenu ng-show="app.checkOffSectionConfig('app_statistic')">
                <a href="#" ui-sref="app.statistic">{{app.translateByLocale('menu_home_statistics')}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What flow you want to get? I am not getting your point

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to overwrite the default behavior by binding it with the click event on the sub menu item.